# Copy protections

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a sheet with formulas in certain cell ranges. This spreadsheet is shared with multiple editors with edit permissions, but to protect formulas I have locked these ranges to prevent editing. I have created a script that duplicates a template and renames the sheet so that the editor can calculate the amount of material to prepare based on a number of people. The code to duplicate the template is template is as follows:

```
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var userTxt = '';

//Select last sheet
function onOpen() {
  var totalSheets = ss.getNumSheets();
  var activateLast = ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[totalSheets - 1]);
}

//
function newSheetWhithName() {

  var result = ui.prompt(
      'Information',
      'Please, type a name',
      ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

  // Answer.
  var button = result.getSelectedButton();
  userTxt = result.getResponseText();
  if (button == ui.Button.OK) {
    // "OK".
    if (userTxt === ''){
      ui.alert('Alert', 'You must type a correct name.', ui.ButtonSet.OK);
    }else{
      duplicateProtectedSheet(userTxt);
    }
  } else if (button == ui.Button.CANCEL) {
    // "Cancel".
    ui.alert('Cancel');
  }
}

function duplicateProtectedSheet(sheetName) {

  var old = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  //Sheet already exists
  if (old) {
    ui.alert('there is already a sheet with that name');

  }else{
    var template = ss.getSheetByName("Template");
    var duplicate = template.copyTo(ss).setName(sheetName);
    var p = template.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET)[0];
    var p2 = duplicate.protect();
    p2.setDescription(p.getDescription());
    p2.setWarningOnly(p.isWarningOnly());  
    if (!p.isWarningOnly()) {
      p2.removeEditors(p2.getEditors());
      p2.addEditors(p.getEditors());

    }
    var ranges = p.getUnprotectedRanges();
    var newRanges = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {
      newRanges.push(duplicate.getRange(ranges[i].getA1Notation()));
    } 
    p2.setUnprotectedRanges(newRanges);
    ss.setActiveSheet(duplicate);
    ui.alert('Created');
  }
}
```

When the editor executes the script it correctly performs the function, except for the permissions, throwing the following error:

Exception: You do not have permission to do this.

Comment: The subject of copying sheets with permissions is well canvassed; would you please describe your research before positing this question. Would you also supply the full error message, including the reference to the line of code - and highlight that line of code in your question.

Comment: Ok. I have edited my question.

Comment: What is the specific line of code that is generating the error?

Comment: p2.addEditors(p.getEditors()) is the specific line

Comment: I'm clutching at straws here... But the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection) mentions that "if the user's edit permission comes from a group, the script throws an exception upon removing the group.". I wonder whether your editors are named individually, or as a group?

Comment: The document is shared individually via emails. The administrator (my account) is the only one who can modify formulas to avoid manipulation problems